# How to convert an object with two arrays in an array of object?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like:

```
descriptionList: ["First", "Second", "Last"]

statusList: ["Jon", "Jim", "Den"]
```

I want to create a list of objects, like this:

```
  "subtasks": [
   {
     "description": First,
     "status": "Jon"
   },
   {
     "description": Second,
     "status": "Jim"
   },
  ....
],
```

Lists can have more than 3 elements.

What I have tried is this:

```
var result = {};
descriptionList.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = statusList[i]);
console.log('result', result);
```

What it prints is this one, which is not what I want:

```
{ First: "Jon", Second: "Jim", Last: "Den" }
```

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with unrelated tags. You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this, which uses an iteration function that gets passed the index (use this to grab the data from the second array) i.e. try filling in `const subtasks = description.map(...)` so you get the descriptions, then add the statuses also.

Comment: I have just tried that way, didnt say it is correct.I was trying to make some object and that put it into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zip both arrays and use `map` to create the expected structure:

```js
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
  return Array(Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length)).fill(0).map((_, idx) => ([arr1[idx], arr2[idx]]));
}

const data = {
  descriptionList: ["First", "Second", "Last"],
  statusList: ["Jon", "Jim", "Den"]
};

const result = {
  subtasks: zip(...Object.values(data)).map(el => ({ description: el[0], status: el[1] }))
};

console.log(result);
```